# View not updating when shared preferences value is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I'm using shared preferences to save user item clicks and then show admob ads after 2 clicks every thing is working fine , but my problem is that when i click on a item 2-3 times the value is saved to shared prefs but the ad is not showing, i have to exit my app and then the ad is shown.

I have searched on google , stackoverflow but nothing helped.

P.s. The item click launches another activity

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    rvWord = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    rvWord.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

    dictionaryAdapter = new DictionaryAdapter(this);
    dictionaryAdapter.setCursor(mDBHelper.getDictionaryWord(""));
    rvWord.setAdapter(dictionaryAdapter);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


    preferences = getSharedPreferences("click_count",MODE_PRIVATE);

    if ( preferences.getInt("count", 0) > 2) {

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

    }
    // Show Notification Daily
    showTimedNotification(this);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the ad is not loaded to show. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) you must load the ads in the onCreate method.

Move the below lines to your onCreate method

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

And load a new ad when the interstitial ad is closed so next time you click the button you can show this already loaded ad. Update the AdListener with the following code. If you need to check the preference value when navigating back, you must use it in the onStart method, because the onCreate method is called only when the app starts freshly. Read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java) to understand android activity lifecycle

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if ( preferences.getInt("count", 0) > 2) {

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
               // Load the next interstitial.
               mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code. You must move the `editor.clear();` inside the if condition. Otherwise before the count becomes greater than 2 the value is cleared. Hope this will fix the issue

Comment: Try to debug your code at `if ( preferences.getInt("count", 0) > 2)` check whether the problem is in ads or count. ie check whether the if condition works properly

Comment: the problem is the if statement doesn't get executed in my main activity when i navigate back from my detail activity, for the sake of curiosity i tried to put the same code in my view holder adapter and it worked fine

Comment: Where do you have this code? Can you post the complete code

Comment: updated my answer. Hope this will help to solve the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193781/discussion-between-john-and-sanoj).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but when i used commit() instead of apply(). it may be work fine.

1. because apply() is an Asynchronous,  it commits without returning a Boolean indicating success or failure.
2. and commit() is an Synchronous and returns true if the save works, false otherwise.